# Google Search - Terminos y consultas

Tags: google-search

Tengo una marca en Internet, cuyo nombre es igual a una palabra bien escrita en ingles y eso dificulta buscar esa marca en Google ya que cada vez que se escribe el nombre de la empresa Google busca la bien buscada palabra y escribe "Quizás querías decir".

Ejemplo: si busco en Google la marca "Ollness", buscará "Illness". El usuario debe presionar "Quizás quisiste decir" para realizar la búsqueda que ya había escrito correctamente al principio y ahí solo aparecerá mi empresa.

¿Alguna vez has encontrado una solución para este tipo de problema?

¡Muchas gracias!